# TypeError when initializing Nco object using python/pynco

Tags: python, typeerror, netcdf, nco, pynco

I am new to using using NCO tools and their Python bindings for working with netCDF files. I have successfully installed the NCO tools and the pynco package (using pip) following the instructions [here](https://github.com/jhamman/pynco). But I am getting an error when I try to initialize an object.

Here are the commands I'm using:

```
from nco import Nco
nco = Nco()
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\nco\nco.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.NCOpath = os.path.split(which('ncks'))[0]
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\ntpath.py", line 180, in split
    d, p = splitdrive(p)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
    if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

This suggests to me that the install may not have worked properly, though I can run NCO commands from the command line.

Any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: The fork of pynco you link is 2 years old. I'd try the original at https://github.com/nco/pynco and as they suggest use the Conda install.

Comment: Thanks, Eric Bridger. I'll give that a go.